# T-trigger: minimum transistor count

Tags: transistors, counter

I am playing around with real implementation of basic logic schemes from transistors.

Could you suggest any compact implementations of T-trigger? Obviously, classic "CMOS" way eats way too many.

Other nonlinear elements are allowed (like tunnel diodes), diodes and other components does not counts.

I will need this to implement binary counter.

Comment: To clarify, are you are talking about a T flip-flop? Are you looking for the smallest physical footprint? Is there a specific reason why you are interested in a discrete transistor implementation, and is that a requirement?

Comment: Yes, T flip-flop. No, it's not smallest physical footprint. Transistor implementation is the whole idea of the project, so it's the core requirement :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people think of this in two layers of abstraction, the logic gate layer and the transistor layer.
To minimize total transistor count, you need to (a) minimize the number of logic gates, and (b) minimize the number of transistors per gate.

You might get some ideas for (a) at [Wikipedia: flip-flop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/flip-flop_%28electronics%29).

For (b), my understanding is that [resistor–transistor logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/resistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic) and [integrated injection logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/integrated_injection_logic) and [diode-transistor logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTL) uses fewer components per logic gate than other logic families.
In order of number of components:

- You can make a 4-input NOR gate out
  of 4 n-channel FETs and a single
  resistor (5 components) with one
  style of RTL, which requires 2 power
  supply rails.
- You can make a 4-input NOR gate out
  of 6 carefully-chosen resistors and a single
  transistor (7 components) with another
  style of RTL ("threshold logic"), but
  it requires 3 power supply rails.
- You can make a 4-input NOR gate out
  of 6 diodes, 3 resistors, and a
  single transistor (10 components)
  with one style of DTL, which requires
  2 power supply rails.

Have you seen "The Transistor Clock"?
It's on [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwWuAasua74) and [Make Magazine](http://blog.makezine.com/archive/2008/06/transistor-clock-kit-uses.html) and the [transistor clock web site](http://www.transistor-clock.com/).

p.s.: Does anyone know what happened to the MT15 CPU, built out of individual discrete transistors?

Comment: Hehe, I wrote an article about MT15 too :-D http://3.14.by/en/read/homemade-cpus

Comment: I see, this transistor clock is using 2T flipflops, similar to ones I am already investigating... I was wondering is there any fancy 1T circuits....

Comment: Well, looks like this transistor clock PDf was quite detailed :-) It's T-trigger is much better than mine, and I easily modded it for my requirements - it is so great, works over such a wide range of params... THanks alot :-D

Comment: BarsMonster: It could probably be done using unijunction transistors, but it's necessary to have positive feedback and that isn't going to happen with a single transistor.  On the other hand, I think the transistor clock parts count could be greatly reduced on the 'output' side.  Assuming one has convenient outputs for a 2+4+3+4+3+4-bit BCD value to be displayed (assuming a little circuitry exists to translates hours into hour-tens and hour-units), and assuming one has a six-phase active-low clock available, one should be able to use 20 transistors to get a multiplexed 4-bit digit value...

Comment: ...and then use one set of ten transistors and ~90 diodes to convert those to digit shapes, and then use seven segment-drive transistors and six digit-drive transistors to drive a multiplexed display.  Even though one would have to add circuitry to yield a fast six-phase clock and convert the hours count to BCD, the savings in parts should still be significant.

Comment: @BarsMonster: BTW, I think it might be possible to reduce the component count for the timekeeping part of the circuit if one multiplexed the counting aspects and used dynamic logic.  The trick would be to essentially build a 5x4 DRAM.  I'd have to work out how to make such a thing actually behave, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to design a T flip-flop using two transistors, some capacitors, and some resistors.  Start by wiring the transistors in a classic bistable multivibrator.  Next, put small capacitors in parallel with the feedback resistors.  The effect will be that if the circuit is sitting with one transistor on it will remain that way (the capacitors will enter a steady state where the cap that's in parallel with the feedback resistor that's passing current will be charged, and the cap in parallel with the other one won't be).  If the circuit is disturbed slightly (e.g. by reducing the supply voltage by a volt) the charged cap will render its associated feedback resistor momentarily ineffective, causing its transistor to turn off.  This will in turn cause the output of that transistor to float to its rail, turning on the other transistor.  Depending upon the exact requirements, there are many variations of the circuit which may be used.

If your goal is to divide down a known frequency, another approach you could use would be to use some relaxation oscillators which can be "nudged", and then have each stage nudge the succeeding one.  For example, suppose one wanted to output one high-going pulse every 3600 high-going pulses of a 60Hz signal (3600 counts).  One could design a two-transistor circuit which would output a high pulse and discharge a cap every time the cap voltage reached 3.0 volts, or any time an input pulse was received and the cap voltage was over 2.0 volts.  One could then cascade six such circuits which would cycle when fed pulses after delays of 75ms, 208ms, 875ms, 4.5s, 12.5s, and 52.5s (effectively yielding divide ratios of 5, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4).  This approach might require some tweaking to ensure reliable operation, but it would a divide-by-3600 using twelve transistors rather than using twenty-four or more.