# Design of A Counter Circuit

Tags: counter

I want to build a counter circuit which to count from from 0-7, during some pulseswidth. The problem I am having is that it has to do the whole count sequence during one PW and that is where I am struggling to come up with an idea

edit: just want to delete question now, sorrry for irrelevance and being unclear

Comment: Are shift registers allowed ? And when you say it has to count in one pulse width do you mean that you pulse the clock once and then it starts counting to 7 or every time you need it to count up you pulse once ?

Comment: Transformers or transistors ?

Comment: "Or if you may have any links to resources that can explain to me how to do it."       One resource:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9757/t-trigger-minimum-transistor-count

Comment: How long is the pulse width?

Comment: Can you use logic gates? Is this a work or school task or something? Only reason I can think of for all the restrictions!

Comment: look at Sequential Switching Bistable Multivibrator at https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/bistable.html

Comment: Asking the same question over and over again is not going to win you any friends here. As should be clear from the comments, no one can understand the requirements (or the implementation constraints) as you've written them, so you need to come up with a way to clearly state or show what the inputs and the outputs of the system need to be, and exactly what must occur when.

Comment: Requirement is to have 4 led-s counting binary from 0 to 7 or to have 7 led-s lighting one by one or what? You can use two OA or two quadruple OA chips?

Comment: Too broad, homework assignment with no effort and OP has asked for it to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You say you are not allowed to use counter ICs..... How about *making* a counter IC?

Counters are made up of flip flops in series with each other. Flip flops can be made with logic gates, or if you are not allowed to use them either, they can be made with transistors. This would solve your LED sequence problem.

As for being able to do the whole thing during one high pulse.... you would have to build a small circuit that would oscillate 7 times during one pulse width to trigger your home made counter.

Comment: Then use transistors as I said to do if you aren't allowed to use logic gates.